# Counting a pivot but faster in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot, crosstab

Currently I am looking for the most efficient way of counting unique combinations from the following table:

```
USER_ID   PRODUCT_TYPE
----------------------
123       yxc
123       asd
123       qwe
456       qwe
789       qwe
789       asd
364       qwe
```

...by running the following code in the Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT qwe + asd + yxc AS sum_prd, qwe, asd, yxc, COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT user_id, product_type
        FROM prd_distribution)
    PIVOT
        (COUNT(product_type)
        FOR product_type IN('qwe' AS qwe, 'asd' AS asd, 'yxc' AS yxc)))
GROUP BY qwe + asd + yxc, qwe, asd, yxc
ORDER BY qwe + asd + yxc;
```

...to get this output here:

```
SUM_PRD   QWE   ASD   YXC   CT
------------------------------
1         1     0     0     2
2         1     1     0     1
3         1     1     1     1
```

Background is, that I do have multiple tables of decent size packed into a bloody slow Oracle DB. Running this code takes ages. So, any hint of improving the efficiency is really appreciated...

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if conditional aggregation would be faster:

```
select num_products,
       sum(case when product_type = 'qwe' then 1 else 0 end) as qwe,
       sum(case when product_type = 'asd' then 1 else 0 end) as asd,
       sum(case when product_type = 'yxc' then 1 else 0 end) as yxc,
       count(distinct user_id) as ct
from (select d.*, count(distinct product_type) over (partition by user_id) as num_products
      from prd_distribution d
     ) d
group by num_products
order by num_products;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this won't produce what I need. This one here however would do so, with `product_types` condensed in one field though. See your own post @GordonLinoff here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811583/sql-unique-combinations)

Comment: Why don't you think this does what you want?